# how to set featured image as facebook post thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have logo image, featured image and one image in footer widget for a page. At the time of posting a page in facebook it is showing footer widget image as first and logo image as 2nd and featured image as third. How to restrict this one to show featured image as first to select as post thumbnail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To get the desired image while sharing or posting post to facebook you
>   have to add `og:image` tag inside your `<head>` tag. And for twitter you have > to use `twitter card`

```
//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype($output)
{
    return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
}

add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//add Open Graph Meta Info
function insert_fb_in_head()
{
    global $post;
    if (!is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;

    if ($excerpt = $post->post_excerpt)
    {
        $excerpt = strip_tags($post->post_excerpt);
    }
    else
    {
        $excerpt = get_bloginfo('description');
    }

    echo '<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR APPID"/>'; //<-- this is optional
    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $excerpt . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="' . get_bloginfo() . '"/>';

    echo '<meta name="twitter:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
    echo '<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />';
    echo '<meta name="twitter:description" content="' . $excerpt . '" />';
    echo '<meta name="twitter:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';

    if (!has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))
    {
        //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image = "http://example.com/image.jpg"; //<--replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
        echo '<meta name="twitter:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else
    {
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr($thumbnail_src[0]) . '"/>';
        echo '<meta name="twitter:image" content="' . esc_attr($thumbnail_src[0]) . '"/>';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5);
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

*Please Note: this code will work for both Facebook and Twitter.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it work for other social applications like twitter?

Comment: @PadminiMaddur: I have updated my code, now it will work for both fb and twitter.

Comment: Hi. I have used your code. Then also am facing same problem. It is not showing featured image. It is showing all the images which is in the page like logo image and content images.

Comment: check your link in this facebook debuger tool. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/. and if possible share your website URL.

Comment: Hi... I am getting this issue. Inferred Property-The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. And it is showing the logo image.

Comment: It might be showing from cache click on "Fetch new" or "scrap again" button for 1 or 2 time, error will disappear. and also check that og:image is present or not inside `<head>` tag in your post or not. Please Note: my answer will only add og tag in `post` not on any page. Do you want it to be on all the pages as well?

Comment: Missing double quote in description tag `echo '<meta property="og:description" content=' . $excerpt . '/>';`.